# How do I send ctrl+c to a process in c#?

Tags: c#, command-line, .net-2.0, process

I'm writing a wrapper class for a command line executable.  This exe accepts input from `stdin` until I hit `Ctrl+C` in the command prompt shell, in which case it prints output to `stdout` based on the input.  I want to simulate that `Ctrl+C` press in C# code, sending the kill command to a .NET `Process` object.  I've tried calling `Process.Kill()`, but that doesn't seem to give me anything in the process's `StandardOutput` `StreamReader`.  Might there be anything I'm not doing right?  Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(exe, args);
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);

p.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(scriptcode);

p.Kill();

string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) 
{
    throw new Exception(error);
}
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

The output is always empty, even though I get data back from `stdout` when I run the exe manually.

**Edit**: This is C# 2.0 by the way.

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer to this question, the [MedallionShell NuGet package](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell#stopping-a-command) contains a cross-platform implementation of this. On Windows, it uses the console attaching method described below, but in a safer way that works around some of the pitfalls.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion this deserves to be its own answer. We all deserve better than the built-in Process type and MedallionShell delivers. Magnificent work, you absolute legend.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've actually just figured out the answer.  Thank you both for your answers, but it turns out that all i had to do was this:

```
p.StandardInput.Close()
```

which causes the program I've spawned to finish reading from stdin and output what i need.

Comment: Note that it only works if the process is trying to read from standard input. Closing the stdin does nothing until the program tries to read something from it.

Comment: why it shows this exception 
"StandardIn has not been redirected." ? 
i am using ffmpeg for screen capturing

Comment: Closing Standard input does not do the same as pressing Control-C. If you have a loop reading input and then close it, since the external application is still running you'll get an error.

Answer (score 57):

Despite the fact that using `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()` for sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal is the right answer, it needs significant clarification to get it to work in different .NET application types.

If your .NET application doesn't use its own console (Windows Forms/WPF/Windows Service/ASP.NET), the basic flow is:

1. Attach the main .NET process to the console of the process that you want to signal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Prevent the main .NET process from stopping because of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event by disabling handling of the signal with `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`.
3. Generate the console event for the *current* console with `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()` (`processGroupId` should be zero! The answer with code that sends `p.SessionId` will not work and is incorrect).
4. Wait for the signaled process to respond (e.g. by waiting for it to exit)
5. Restore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handling by main process and disconnect from console.

The following code snippet illustrates how to do that:

```cs
Process p;
if (AttachConsole((uint)p.Id)) {
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, true);
    try { 
        if (!GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0))
            return false;
        p.WaitForExit();
    } finally {
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, false);
        FreeConsole();
    }
    return true;
}
```

where `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`, `FreeConsole()`, `AttachConsole()` and `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()` are native WinAPI methods:

```cs
internal const int CTRL_C_EVENT = 0;
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(uint dwCtrlEvent, uint dwProcessGroupId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern bool FreeConsole();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlDelegate HandlerRoutine, bool Add);
// Delegate type to be used as the Handler Routine for SCCH
delegate Boolean ConsoleCtrlDelegate(uint CtrlType);
```

Note that waiting for the targeted process to respond, typically by waiting for the process to exit, is critical. Otherwise, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal will remain in the current process's input queue and when handling is restored by the second call to `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`, that signal will terminate the *current* process, rather than the targeted one.

Things become more complex if you need to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from .NET console application. The above approach will not work because `AttachConsole()` returns `false` in this case (the main console app already has a console). It is possible to call `FreeConsole()` before `AttachConsole()` call, but doing so will result in the original .NET app console being lost, which is not acceptable in most cases.

Here is my solution for this case; it works and has no side effects for the .NET main process console:

1. Create small supporting .NET console program that accepts process ID from command line arguments, loses its own console with `FreeConsole()` before the `AttachConsole()` call and sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to the target process with code mentioned above.
2. The main .NET console process just invokes this utility in a new process when it needs to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to another console process.
3. In the main .NET console process call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, true)` before spawning the "killer"-process (from step 1) and `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, false)` after. Else your main process will also receive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and die

Comment: This works on .NET Framework, but I couldn't get this running with .NET 5.0. The AttachConsole call fails with error code 5 (access denied).

Comment: @candritzky take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700848/attach-console-to-process

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I cannot see what it should tell me.

Should it tell me that I should not call AttachConsole (as mentioned by @Shadow4571)? I already tried this and it doesn't work.

Or should it tell me that I should migrate from .NET 5.0 to .NET Framework 4.8? That's not an option for us for the problem at hand (which is as simple as "sending a Ctrl+C signal from a parent process to a .NET Core child process on Windows").

Comment: This is a great response - I got a .NET 5 service to attach to a console and send Ctrl + C successfully following these steps, but you really do have to follow them all, in order. I tried skipping some and no dice.

Answer (score 25):

@alonl: The user is attempting to wrap a command-line program.  Command-line programs don't have message pumps unless they are specifically created, and even if that was the case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't have the same semantics in a Windows-environment application (copy, by default) as it does in a command-line environment (Break).

I threw this together. CtrlCClient.exe simply calls `Console.ReadLine()` and waits:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("CtrlCClient.exe");
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is active: {1}", proc.Id, !proc.HasExited);
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("\x3");
    Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is active: {1}", proc.Id, !proc.HasExited);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My output seems to do what you want:

> ```
> 4080 is active: True
> 4080 is active: False
> ```

Hope that helps!

(To clarify: `\x3` is the hex escape sequence for the hex character 3, which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  It's not just a magic number. ;) )

Comment: Using a test program that both assigns Console.CancelKeyPress delegate and do a Console.ReadLine(); the proposed solution of StandardInput.WriteLine("\x3"); does complete the ReadLine call but does not (for me) trigger the CancelKeyPress delegate. Bug / incorrect correctness demonstration because any input, not just ctrl+c, triggers a process exit? (Hitting ctrl+c on the keyboard does trigger the delegate for me)

Comment: @David Burg: Possibly a bugfix in framework code?  The post was authored three versions and > 4 years ago.

Comment: To clarify (Sorry for gravedig), this doesn't work if you're not reading from stdin, as it doesn't actually send the signal

Answer (score 11):

Ok, here is a solution.

The way to send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> signal is with GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent. HOWEVER, this call takes a processGroupdID parameter, and sends the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> signal to all processes in the group. This would be fine if it weren't for the fact that there is no way spawn child process in .net that is in a different process group than you (the parent) are in. So, when you send the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent, both the child AND YOU (THE PARENT) GET IT. So, you need to capture the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> event in the parent too, and then determine if you ned to ignore it not.

In my case, I want the parent to be able to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> events also, so I need to distnguish between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> events sent by the user on the console, and those sent by the parent process to the child. I do this by just hackishly setting/unsetting a boolean flag while send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to the child, and then checking for this flag in the parent's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> event handler (ie. if send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to child, then ignore.)

So, the code would look something like this:

```
//import in the declaration for GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]  
static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(ConsoleCtrlEvent sigevent, int dwProcessGroupId);
public enum ConsoleCtrlEvent  
{  
    CTRL_C = 0,  
    CTRL_BREAK = 1,  
    CTRL_CLOSE = 2,  
    CTRL_LOGOFF = 5,  
    CTRL_SHUTDOWN = 6  
}

//set up the parents CtrlC event handler, so we can ignore the event while sending to the child
public static volatile bool SENDING_CTRL_C_TO_CHILD = false;
static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = SENDING_CTRL_C_TO_CHILD;
}

//the main method..
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    //hook up the event handler in the parent
    Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(Console_CancelKeyPress);

    //spawn some child process
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.Arguments = "childProcess.exe";
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();

    //sned the ctrl-c to the process group (the parent will get it too!)
    SENDING_CTRL_C_TO_CHILD = true;
    GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(ConsoleCtrlEvent.CTRL_C, p.SessionId);        
    p.WaitForExit();
    SENDING_CTRL_C_TO_CHILD = false;

    //note that the ctrl-c event will get called on the parent on background thread
    //so you need to be sure the parent has handled and checked SENDING_CTRL_C_TO_CHILD
    already before setting it to false. 1000 ways to do this, obviously.



    //get out....
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couple improvements to the import per StyleCop and FxCop rules. Too long for comment so will attempt inline...

Comment: `p.SessionId` is not a correct parameter to `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`.

Comment: This code can't work. GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent requires process group id, not terminal session id.

Comment: Struggling with this same problem, this answer didn't do it for me, always provided an error 87 (Invalid parameter). Instead, I used p.Id and, although it still didn't send the Ctrl-C to my process, `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` at least doesn't give any error now..

Comment: You do not need to wait for the process to exit. You can sleep for long enough to ensure that all threads affected by the signal have been scheduled

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, in my case, what I wanted is, from a console process, create a child console process (ffmpeg.exe for that matter) and support clean <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> handling in my process and in the child process (ffmpreg exits normally when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed which is a nice feature I wanted to keep working)

None of the solution I found here were working, so I just interop'd Windows' [CreateProcess function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and it just works w/o any effort, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is automatically received by the child app and by the parent app, input and output streams are shared, etc. I was not able to reproduce that kind of code using the standard .NET Process class:

```
    static void RunFFMpeg(string arguments)
    {
        var startup = new STARTUPINFO();
        startup.cb = Marshal.SizeOf<STARTUPINFO>();
        if (!CreateProcess(null, "ffmpeg.exe " + arguments, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref startup, out var info))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        CloseHandle(info.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(info.hThread);

        var process = Process.GetProcessById(info.dwProcessId);
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("Abort.");
            // end of program is here
        };

        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("Exit.");
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public int dwX;
        public int dwY;
        public int dwXSize;
        public int dwYSize;
        public int dwXCountChars;
        public int dwYCountChars;
        public int dwFillAttribute;
        public int dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcess(
       string lpApplicationName,
       string lpCommandLine,
       IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
       IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
       bool bInheritHandles,
       int dwCreationFlags,
       IntPtr lpEnvironment,
       string lpCurrentDirectory,
       ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
       out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
```

Answer (score -6):

Try actually sending the Key Combination Ctrl+C, instead of directly terminating the process:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(
              int hWnd,      // handle to destination window
              uint Msg,       // message
              long wParam,  // first message parameter
              long lParam   // second message parameter
              );
```

Look it up on the MSDN, you should find what you need there in order to send the Ctrl+Key combination...
I know that the message you need for sending Alt+Key is WM_SYSTEMKEYDOWN and WM_SYSTEMKEYUP, can't tell you about Ctrl...

Comment: What if the process is started hidden without a window ?