# How to send keystrokes to application UI automation -C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, automation

i need to find out automationid for key board values? how to send keystrokes to application UI automation? i need to automate page up and page down function in key board. What is the best way to do 
it?

**EDIT:**
in my application following the process. Assume end user open MS Word document with 5 pages and he presses page up and page down buttons to move within these pages. i want to automate this scenario using c#. currently i have uses UIAutomationClient.dll and UIAutomationTypes.dll. can i uses these?

Comment: @Sirwani Has nothing to do with it. He wasn't to simulate keystrokes on an external application.

Comment: Try a combination of WinApi call to SetForegroundWindow and SendKeys

Comment: i have tried this one. but for that i need automationid. http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET20&Lang=EN

Comment: @YoryeNathan i need to automate . i have edited my question. plz check. thanx

Comment: Not 100%ly sure whether you mean keystroke (i. e. simulating the press of a key on keyboard) or buttonpush (i. e. simulating clicking with a mouse on a button). For the first, you do not need an AutomationId, for the latter, it is one way - since for the mouse click you will need screen coordinates, then you can use the ClickablePoint of the AutomationElement you got. For the first, use SendKeys.Send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this scenario get the word document to fore ground and then used on screen key board
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");`and click page up and down buttons using mouse input
since for the mouse click need screen coordinates for the page up and down button.

( i tried to detect on screen key board using UI automation. but it did not detect keys of the screen. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077738/windows-sdk-inspect-tool-what-are-the-reasons-on-screen-keyboard-does-not-disp couldn't find solution for this problem.so because of that i use this move click method to click the button. )

Answer (score 4):

A very good way for automated sending of keystrokes of all kinds is the [AutoIt automation and scripting language](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). Lots can be done with it, especially page up and page down sending.

I suggest writing an EXE with autoit, which connects itself to the program it will send keystrokes to.

Comment: AutoIt can do that! but C# isn't required, as you can compile AutoIt script on its own. AND you can use it within C#... but it's not required

Answer (score 4):

1. Active the application's window using P/Invoke.
2. Call `SendWait("C")` with any character.

E.g.

```
// Get a handle to an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

// Activate an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// Send a series of key presses to the Calculator application. 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class 
    // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
    IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("CalcFrame","Calculator");

    // Verify that Calculator is a running process. 
    if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
        return;
    }

    // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it  
    // a set of calculations.
    SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
    SendKeys.SendWait("111");
    SendKeys.SendWait("*");
    SendKeys.SendWait("11");
    SendKeys.SendWait("=");
}
```

See [How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) > "To send a keystroke to a different application"

Comment: Sometime, it will be useful to add time delay using Thread.Sleep(100) after SetForegroundWindow call and before sending keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to send keystrokes to an application for which you don't have source code.
I can't help you telling you how to do it directly in C#.
But you can do it very easily with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/); it has a DLL you can reference in C# to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read
[How to send keys instead of characters to a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274668/how-to-send-keys-instead-of-characters-to-a-process)

This tells you exactly how to send keys to an application.

Answer (score 1):

//
use a windows form and use this list with send key 
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm
I'm pretty sure he's just asking for values of the keys for his SendKey.Send("{}");

Comment: Please post constructed answer and then references.