# Send CTRL_C/SIGINT to a process from C#

Tags: c#, console, pinvoke

I would like to interrupt a command running through cmd.exe. In the code below, I am using ping www.stackoverflow.com -t as an example.

```
    public void Run()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");

        si.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        si.RedirectStandardError = true;
        si.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.CreateNoWindow = false;
        //si.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        System.Diagnostics.Process console = new Process();
        console.StartInfo = si;

        console.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        console.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
        console.ErrorDataReceived += proc_ErrorDataReceived;

        console.Start();

        console.BeginOutputReadLine();
        console.BeginErrorReadLine();

        console.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping www.stackoverflow.com -t");

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        bool success = GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent((uint)0, (uint)console.SessionId);
        if (!success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }

        char asdf = (char)0x3;

        console.StandardInput.WriteLine('\x3');
        console.StandardInput.WriteLine(asdf);
        console.StandardInput.Write(asdf);

        //console.StandardInput.Close();

        console.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");
        console.WaitForExit();
    }
```

The error code from GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent is 6.

I have followed the instructions from:

1. [Can I send a ctrl-C (SIGINT) to an application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows)
2. http://pastebin.com/vQuWQD8F
3. [How to send keys instead of characters to a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274668/how-to-send-keys-instead-of-characters-to-a-process)

However, I am unable to interrupt the process.

Any help greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

This can be a very common problem with sending keys as well as some other messages, to an application. Remember, that if the application you are sending to has higher permissions evaluation than your program, it usually will not succeed in sending the keys or message. Try running your program under administrative privileges. Or, if you are debugging through Visual Studio, run Visual Studio under administrative privileges.

***EDIT:***

seeing as how this is not your problem you want to take a look at using the `ServiceController` class documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28VS.80%29.aspx). It allows much finer control than `Process` does and is highly recommended for reliability in these situations. I will leave my previous answer simply because its a common problem that someone else may find helpful

Here are two tutorials to get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31688/Using-the-ServiceController-in-C-to-stop-and-start
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/servicecontroller-in-C-Sharp/

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you, but this is not my problem. just confirmed that running Visual Studio as administrator

Comment: I would really like so be able to send Key combinations just so I have the flexibility. It seems like it is possible, but I am just doing something wrong.