# C# copy to clipboard - third party

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I would like to create an program like a text module in background. With a shortcut like ALT+A I am going to simulate an double click at the current cursor position (to select a word in a **third party application**) and use sendkeys CTRL + C to copy the text into my clipboard.

But sendkeys does not work to copy the selected text to clipboard. Is it possible to realize an application like this?

```
        //Jump to cursor position
        SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);

        //Simulate double click
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);

        //Copy to clipboard
        SendKeys.SendWait("^C");
        
        //Show Clipboard Text
        MessageBox.Show(Clipboard.GetText());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for your reply. SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)"); does not work.

Comment: Does it work if you have a `Thread.Sleep(10000);` after the `SendWait`?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563696/use-sendmessage-in-c-sharp-to-perform-a-ctrl-c-operation-on-a-given-handle ?

Comment: thread.sleep does not help. I will try wm_copy.

Comment: Is there a selection (e.g. text) such that there is actually something to copy?

Comment: Yes, its about copying selected text.

Answer (score 0):

topic can be closed, I found here a solution:

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235972/copy-and-modify-selected-text-in-different-application)

Thanks!

Comment: There is a [delete] button below your question....