# How to shutdown java application correctly from C# one

Tags: c#, java, shutdown-hook

I have java application which shutdowns correctly when i use `CTRL-C`, java application saves all data before shutdown. Now i trying to shutdown this java application from my C# console application using `Process.Close()`, but application dont't save any data when i use this, i also tried `Process.CloseMainWindow()` but using this nothing is happening, and also `Process.Kill()` but using this process just killed, without any savining.

How can i raise shutdown hook on java application from C# console application?

Comment: do you already have a shutdown hook in your app and Process.close() does not trigger it?

Comment: ok, sorry, didn't read the question carefully

Comment: is your shutdown hook executed when you end the program from task manager? if so, you can try posting WM_QUIT or WM_CLOSE messages to your java process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shutdown hook cannot be raised by another app.

**The shutdown hook runs when:**

- A program exists normally. For example, `System.exit()` is called, or
  the last non-daemon thread exits.
- the Virtual Machine is terminated. e.g. CTRL-C. This corresponds to
  kill -SIGTERM pid or kill -15 pid on Unix systems.

**The shutdown hook will not run when:**

- the Virtual Machine aborts
- A SIGKILL signal is sent to the Virtual Machine process on Unix
  systems. e.g. kill -SIGKILL pid or kill -9 pid
- A TerminateProcess call is sent to the process on Windows systems.

Comment: Thanks! Waht i should use to run shutdown hook on windows, from my C# application?

Comment: How can i send CTRL-C signal to java application

Comment: I would suggest rather trying to kill the process using cmd? I cannot however say for sure it will work, see here for more: http://techmonks.net/windowsxp-using-the-command-prompt-to-see-and-kill-processes/ you'll have to test it, Though a draw back would be your jar's portability.

Comment: @Robert this might help for sending the CTRL-C to your Java console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517586/c-send-ctrlc-to-console-program-started-with-process-start see the answers link