# How to end a ruby script in a process in C# application or in general how to end a process?

Tags: c#, process

I have a ruby script which I am trying to execute using Process from my program. After certain event, I want to stop its execution. I tried sending the ctrl + c using the solution provided in the quetsion [How do I send ctrl+c to a process in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283128/how-do-i-send-ctrlc-to-a-process-in-c) however its not working for me. Can anyone provide better solution?
Below is the code:

`string command = @"/c ruby C:\MyRubyProgram GetThis GetThat";`

```
        ProcessStartInfo start_info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", command);
        start_info.UseShellExecute = false;
        start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start_info.RedirectStandardInput=true;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = start_info;

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("\x3");
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.Write(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `process.Kill()` ? It should help..

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to kill the process. When it is finished.

```
process.WaitForExit();
```