# C# Ping -t stopping by button

Tags: c#, ping

I have little problem with stopping infinite Pinging.

[image]

If you see in picture I ping IP 127.0.0.1 it has infinite ping ( -t ).
And I want do that when I Click Stop! button then it stops pinging.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Management;

namespace PingProgramm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Thread th;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th = new Thread(thread1);
            th.Start();
        }

        public void thread1()
        {
            try
            {
                string command = "/c ping -t " + textBox1.Text;
                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD", command);
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
                proc.Start();
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //if an error occurs with in the try block, it will handled here.
            }
        }
        void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
                MethodInvoker append = () => richTextBox1.Text += newLine;
                richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(append);
            }
        }
        bool firstTime = true;
        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstTime)
            {
                firstTime = false;
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Best wishes

KLDesigns,

Comment: So what have you tried to do in terms of stopping your ping command process

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that might work in your current code is to get hold of your `Process` instance in the DataReceived event and cancel the process there (or send a Ctrl+C on the stdin).

```
void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (stop) 
    {
         // sender is our process instance
         // so we can cast that safely here
         var proc = (Process) sender;
         // brutally kill it
         proc.Kill();
         // or more gently, send a ctrl+C
         // http://stackoverflow.com/a/285041/578411
         proc.StandardInput.Close();
    }
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
        MethodInvoker append = () => richTextBox1.Text += newLine;
        richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(append);
     }
}
```

You can set the boolean `stop` in your click event handler:

```
    bool stop = false;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         stop = true;
    }
```

Keep in mind that if you want to keep control over object instances you create consider keeping a reference to them. As you create the `Process` inside the thread your form can't reach it any more. If you would have made the `proc` an member of your form you could have called `proc.StandardInput.Close()` from your click event.