# How to run code when a scheduled task is terminated

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

We're running a C# console program as a scheduled task on Windows. This program itself runs a lot of "tasks" that would need to be gracefully shutdown when the program itself is ended.

Is there a way to run cleanup code (that could take a second or two) when the scheduled task is ended? For instance when it is ended by calling `Stop-ScheduledTask` from a PowerShell script.

I've tried catching CTRL-C events as well as catching the `ProcessExit` event of `AppDomain`, but none of these appear to be called when the scheduled task is ended.

As outlined by *rrirower* in the comments, another option would be to send a signal to the process before asking it to terminate, but this does not seem better supported on Windows.

Comment: Any reason why the script can't run the cleanup code?

Comment: It could if there was a way to send a signal to the process, which is another option I'm investigating (no idea how to do that cleanly on Windows, though `taskkill` seems to be one way).

Comment: @Damith Not sure how triggers help here...

Comment: @rrirower One situation that wouldn't work is when the Task is killed before it's finished. You can configure the Task Scheduler to kill a previous instance if it's not finished by the next scheduled start time.

Comment: @AndyJ Even that would be fine. _Any_ way to tell the program to gracefully shut down its tasks would be fine. Reliably sending a CTRL-C signal would be one way but that doesn't look doable. One option I've found is to use stdin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283128/how-do-i-send-ctrlc-to-a-process-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making an HTTP query to the REST API of the program to ask it to terminate its tasks, right before I terminate the scheduled task:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri ("{0}/Application/TerminateAllTasks" -f $programUrl)
$p = Get-Process "NameOfTheProcess" -ErrorAction Stop
$task | Stop-ScheduledTask -ErrorAction Stop
$p.WaitForExit()
```

In the longer run, we will convert the program to a proper Windows service, which will make graceful termination easier.