# FFmpeg Concat Corrupts Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm using FFmpeg to encode video in several segments. For example, the user can encode 500 frames, close it, then resume to encode another 1300 frames, close it, and resume to encode another 700 frames.

At this point, I have 3 x265 streams in MKV files which I want to concatenate into a single file. I have no audio at this point.

I use this command to concatenate the 3 files into 1. However, the video file then plays with errors, skipping frames, changing speed or displaying artifacts at the junction points.

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -fflags +genpts -async 1 -safe 0 -i "MergeList.txt" -c copy "Job5_Output.mp4"
```

What's the right way of concatenating my files?

The issue might be that I'm concatenating partial files (when the process was killed). I tried first muxing from MKV into MP4 to produce a valid file container, and then concatenating those MP4 files. The output has less corruption, but there are still visual glitches at the intersection points. The frame count is correct. The output file matches the frame count of all segments.

I just tried again with h264; the result is the same as with h265.

Comment: Are these segments interrupted mid-encode?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to implement a "Pause / Resume" feature.

Comment: Soft or hard exit?

Comment: I'm doing a hard exit. I could alter the code to request a soft exit.

Comment: You should. x265 probably doesn't get to clean up.

Comment: I'm searching and searching... it's really not easy to close a hidden process in C#!! CloseMainWindow doesn't work when CreateNoWindow is true. The only recommendation I can find is to call Kill, which we know the downside.

Comment: I found a way, now merging works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that killing FFmpeg didn't give it time to clean up its output file, resulting in corruption.

However, doing a soft kill on a hidden process in .NET is not easy.

After plenty of research, I found this solution that works.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29274238/3960200