# Attach console to process

Tags: c#, .net-core, monogame

I want to attach a console to an monogame application. I used .Net Framework at first and everything worked fine, then I switched to .Net Core 3.1 and the console stopped attaching to the process.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

[DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "AllocConsole")]
[return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "GetStdHandle")]
private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(Int32 nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool FreeConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetLastError")]
private static extern int GetLastError();

private void InitializeConsole() {
    if (AttachConsole(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id) && AllocConsole()) {
        GetStdHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        _isInitializeConsole = true;
    } else {
        _isInitializeConsole = false;
        throw new Exception($"Console alloc error code: {GetLastError()}");
    }
}
```

When trying to attach a console from the AttachConsole method, I get result "false" and last error code - 5 (Access is denied). I ran the application as administrator and getting error code - 6 (The handle is invalid).

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: You need to check the return value of _each_ P/Invoke call, not just the combined `&&` result, because `GetLastError` could be reporting _either_ `AttachConsole` _or_ `AllocConsole` failing and you don't know which.

Comment: Why are you calling `AttachConsole` at all? That's for cross-process console sharing, but from what I can tell you're doing this all in a single process?

Comment: You're calling `GetStdHandle` incorrectly: needs a handle-number, _not_ a process-id: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle

Comment: If you are using .net, why not just use the console functions provided with C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Dai Indeed, when I removed the `AttachConsole` everything worked. For some reason, on Net Framework, I needed to execute AttachConsole, because without that the console would not appear.

Comment: @Shadow4571 I'm guessing that's due to interactions with Visual Studio's debugger and stdout redirection - does it differ based on if you started the project from within VS or not?

Comment: @Dai, yes, the project has been moved from Visual Studio to Rider.